# can't download images from aws s3 although all things is correct in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i use `aws-sdk` for download images from aws s3 code no error but no any image download

```
const filePath = '../imgs';
const bucketName = 'xxx';
const key =  "uploads/imgs/logo.png";

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = "xxxxxx";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "xxxxxxxx";
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
const fs = require('fs')
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

const s3download = (bucketName, keyName, localDest) => {

    if (typeof localDest == 'undefined') {
        localDest = keyName;
    }

    let params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: keyName
    }

    let file = fs.createWriteStream(localDest)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
            .on('end', () => {
                return resolve();
            })
            .on('error', (error) => {
                return reject(error);
            }).pipe(file)
    });
};
s3download(bucketName, key, filePath)
```

when print result appear this

```
_readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: false,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { prefinish: [Function: prefinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    buffered: [],
    bufferedIndex: 0,
    allBuffers: true,
    allNoop: true,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    errored: false,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false
  },
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @BadPiggie no error but image not download

Comment: It's difficult to guess what the problem is without more information, did you try to run in debug with breakpoints? or add prints? All I can say for this input is that the following worked for me so you can try it:
Try to replace from `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` until the end of the function, with: `return Promise.resolve(s3.getObject(params).createReadStream());` it returns a thenable so you can follow up with a `.then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: @alfasin please review question i add result of data

Comment: looks like in `filePath` you provide the path to the folder but not the expected filename. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @alfasin i have imgs folder like `imgs, node_modules, package.json, index.js` i run node index.js

Comment: you didn't understand what I wrote: when you save the object locally into a file you should provide a file-name: right now you provide only the folder when you're doing: `let file = fs.createWriteStream(localDest)`

Comment: @alfasin thanks . yes i add folder only no name of file . please add this answer for accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filePath` provides the path to the folder where we want to save the file that we get from S3 but we do not provide a *filename* here:

```
let file = fs.createWriteStream(localDest)
```

`localDest` should be a full-path + filename and currently it only provides the full path